# Admob slowing down webview

Tags: android, webview, admob

I have an app with html content in webview. When I load rewarded ads from `Admob`, my webview animations aren't smooth anymore. When I profile my webview with Chrome dev tools it actually shows a lot of `Admob`-related things using main webview thread.
What I tried to fix this:

- Use webview from another thread. While I can create a webview, it crashes on adding it to existing LinearLayout. Even though I add it in UI thread, it still complains that there is an UI operation outside of ui thread.
- Creating a separate activity in different process. This activity stays in the background. Loading the ad works fine. Then I bring that activity to front and call `rewardedAd.show()` but nothing happens, until there is an error callback because of timeout. No details.

Did anyone manage to solve performance issues with `Admob`-rewarded ads slowing down webview?

Comment: I have a similar problem with my browser game on Phaser. The FPS drops dramatically in Canvas scenes with AdMob initialized. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @sede10g what Admob SDK version you are using?

Comment: You ever find a solution? I'm facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code:-->

Your View XMl

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

In your Java/Kotlin code, get a reference to the WebView and load AdMob ads into it. You can do this by creating an HTML page that includes AdMob ad code and loading this HTML page into the WebView.

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var webView: WebView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)

    // Enable JavaScript in WebView (required for AdMob ads)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    // Load your HTML page with AdMob ads
    val htmlContent = "<html><body><script async src=\"https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script> <ins class=\"adsbygoogle\" style=\"display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px\" data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\" data-ad-slot=\"1234567890\"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></body></html>"
    webView.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8")
}}
```

**Test on real device **

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest

 val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID")
.build()
 webView.loadUrl("your_admob_url", adRequest)
```

**Handle AdMob Ads Events:**

You can also handle ad events, such as ad loading, clicking, and error handling, by using AdMob's ad listeners. Refer to the AdMob documentation for more details on handling these events.